# SQL Insert with Select and OUTPUT to create a temp copy table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I make a copy of the inserted records and keep the original id of the record it copied and put it in the Temp table. 
When I add Docs.DocID to the OUTPUT I get. "The multi-part identifier "Docs.DocID" could not be bound."

```
DECLARE @CopiedDocIDs TABLE(NewDocID int, CurrentDocID int)

INSERT INTO Docs (Filename,Backup)
OUTPUT INSERTED.DocID, Docs.DocID INTO @CopiedDocIDs 
SELECT Filename, 1
FROM Docs 
WHERE Filename like 'MyDoc%'
```

Oh yeah I'm working with: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64)

**EDIT:** Ok somewhat of a hack but it works. Here's it working but I'll add in another column to the RowKey just make sure it's unique.

```
DECLARE @Docs TABLE (DocID int IDENTITY(1, 1), [FileName] varchar(10), FileDate datetime)
INSERT INTO @Docs VALUES('Doc1','01-01-2011 12:21:12:003')
INSERT INTO @Docs VALUES('Doc2','01-01-2013 02:41:32:120')
INSERT INTO @Docs VALUES('Doc3','01-01-2014 09:30:12:023')
INSERT INTO @Docs VALUES('Doc','01-01-2014 09:30:12:111')
INSERT INTO @Docs VALUES('Doc','01-01-2014 09:30:15:123')

DECLARE @NewDocIDs TABLE(NewDocID int, CopyDocID int, RowKey Varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @Docs ([FileName],FileDate)
OUTPUT INSERTED.DocID, null, (INSERTED.[FileName]+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(50),INSERTED.FileDate,126)) INTO @NewDocIDs
SELECT [FileName],FileDate
FROM @Docs 

UPDATE @NewDocIDs SET CopyDocID=(SELECT TOP 1 DocID FROM @Docs WHERE [FileName]+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(50),FileDate,126)=RowKey) 

select * from @Docs
select * from @NewDocIDs --## output I need
```

[image]

Comment: The `Inserted.DocID` is the newly inserted `DocID` - and you're already selecting that.... so what are you trying to achieve, really?? If you **insert** a new row - there's no "pre-existing* "old" `DocID` ....

Comment: If am not wrong you need `update`

Comment: @marc_s The "old" is what's being copied from using the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in 2005. All you can do is to add column to Docs table:

```
Alter table Docs Add OriginalDocID int null;
GO

DECLARE @CopiedDocIDs TABLE(NewDocID int, CurrentDocID int)

INSERT INTO Docs (Filename,Backup,OriginalDocID)
OUTPUT INSERTED.DocID, INSERTED.OriginalDocID INTO @CopiedDocIDs 
SELECT Filename, 1, DocID
FROM Docs 
WHERE Filename like 'MyDoc%'
```

If you have >=2008 then MERGE statement will help:

```
DECLARE @CopiedDocIDs TABLE(NewDocID int, CurrentDocID int)

MERGE INTO Docs AS TGT
USING(SELECT DocID, Filename
FROM Docs 
WHERE Filename like 'MyDoc%') AS SRS
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES(SRS.FileName, 1)
OUTPUT Inserted.DocID, SRS.DocID;
```

Comment: Darn it I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `inserted (or deleted)` values for `OUTPUT` statement.

But this `MERGE` statement probably is what you needed.

```
MERGE INTO Docs
USING Docs AS dc
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(Filename, Backup) Values(dc.Filename, 1)
OUTPUT inserted.DocID, dc.DocID INTO 
  @CopiedDocIDs(NewDocID, CurrentDocID)
```

But unfortunately MERGE is for SQL Server >2008